# Update User License Field and Profile Field In Standard Object User using SOQL or Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

CAn anybody please help me to update user license filed and profile field of user standard object in salesforce using SOQL or apex? i do alot of search on it bt unable to find anything. So if anybody hv any idea so please share.

Thanks,
kp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way of changing a license except for modifying the user directly in the administration screens. Also, I can't imagine in many scenarios you'd have spare licenses to assign to people.

Same deal for profile, being able to modify that through code would open up a whole new set of security risks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i hv 2 user licenses for the customer portal user so on the basis of their login count. i want to assign them the licenses. Working manually makes my life miserable. Any More Ideas.????

Comment: Ah, creating users is a different matter. You can simply create a new instance of User with the right field values and insert it. I believe the profile has to be the name of a portal profile and then it will pick up that license when it's inserted into the system.